# Difference in margin of error for boostrap and parametric approaches in survey

Tags: survey, error

I'd like to know if using a bootstrap-derived margin-of-error for a simple survey is appropriate. I'm worried that the estimate is too small. I've pasted the code below for both approaches for context.

I conducted a simple poll of political opinions with a sample size of about 450 respondents.

I calculated a bootstrapped MoE by sampling one of the 3 values (support, oppose, don't know) from the dataframe 5000 times. Then, I calculated the proportion of each of those values at the 5th, 50th, and 95th percentiles. To get a conservative MoE, I took the maximum difference between either the 50th and 5th or 50th and 95th. Ends up being about 2.8% for the value with the largest proportion (about 68% of respondents support).

When I use a more traditional parametric approach, I get a larger margin of error (4.3%). This makes a difference because I'll need to collect more responses if the bootstrapped version is incorrect and some of my questions are closer to 50% support.

Is there a reason why the parametric and bootstrapped versions are so different? Is one more appropriate to report?

Bootstrap MoE

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = df['q1'][df['q1'] != 'NA']

print ('sample size: ', len(data))

# Initialize a dictionary to store counts for each value
value_counts_dict = {value: [] for value in np.unique(data)}

# Bootstrap sampling loop
for i in range(5000):
    # Create a bootstrap sample
    bs_sample = np.random.choice(data, size=len(data), replace=True)

    # Count the occurrences of each unique entry in the bootstrap sample
    value_counts = {value: np.sum(bs_sample == value) for value in np.unique(data)}

    # Append counts to the dictionary
    for value, count in value_counts.items():
        value_counts_dict[value].append(count)

# Create a DataFrame from the dictionary
df_bootstrap = pd.DataFrame(value_counts_dict)

# Calculate confidence intervals for each column
confidence_intervals = df_bootstrap.quantile([0.05, 0.5, 0.95])

confidence_intervals_percentage = confidence_intervals.div(confidence_intervals.sum(axis=1), axis=0) * 100


# Calculate the differences between the 50th percentile and both the 95th and 5th percentiles for each column
difference_50_95 = confidence_intervals_percentage.loc[0.5] - confidence_intervals_percentage.loc[0.95]
difference_50_05 = confidence_intervals_percentage.loc[0.5] - confidence_intervals_percentage.loc[0.05]

# Take the larger of the two differences for each column
max_differences = difference_50_95.abs().combine(difference_50_05.abs(), max)

# Find the item (column) with the largest of these max differences
largest_max_difference_item = max_differences.idxmax()
largest_max_difference_value = max_differences.max()

# Add a new row called "moe" with the value of the largest max difference for each column
# Here, we actually want to add this as a specific value which reflects the largest difference observed
confidence_intervals_percentage.loc["moe"] = max_differences

(largest_max_difference_item, largest_max_difference_value, confidence_intervals_percentage)
```

Parametric MoE

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

# Example DataFrame creation
# df = pd.DataFrame({'q1': ['support', 'oppose', 'no opinion / na', 'NA', 'support', 'oppose', ...]})

# Calculate the total number of responses excluding 'NA'
n = len(df['q1'][df['q1'] != 'NA'])

# Confidence level to Z-score for 95% confidence level
Z = norm.ppf(0.975)  # Two-tailed

# Initialize a dictionary to hold MoE for each category
moe_dict = {}

for category in ['no opinion / na', 'oppose', 'support']:
    # Calculate proportion for the category
    p = len(df['q1'][df['q1'] == category]) / n
    
    # Calculate MoE for the category
    MoE = Z * np.sqrt((p * (1 - p)) / n) *100
    
    # Store the MoE in the dictionary
    moe_dict[category] = MoE

# Display the MoE for each category
for category, MoE in moe_dict.items():
    print(f"Margin of Error for '{category}': {MoE:.4f}")
```